# jQuery: make letters disappear when outside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm a beginner at jQuery and I made this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vwnp2do6/

```
        $(this).children('.comname').children('.comtitle').animate({
            left: '-=200px'
        }, {
            queue: true,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).children('.comname').children('.comcontent').animate({
            right: '-=200px'
        }, {
            queue: true,
            duration: 500
        });
```

I think it's clear what I want to accomplish but I don't understand why the title and the description are reappearing again when they are done animating. They seem to disappear outside the div, but when they're completely outside it, they reappear again. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `overflow: hidden;` to your div with the id `comite`
http://jsfiddle.net/vwnp2do6/1/
is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Such a simple solution haha. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I know, that's because the right value should be bigger

Answer (score 2):

Add an `overflow:hidden` to *.comname* selector. And also move 300px the title and caption of the image:

```
.comname {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #575650;
  font-family:"Century Gothic";
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 238px;
  height: 82px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #c4c3b3;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The js:

```
        $(this).children('.comname').children('.comtitle').animate({
            left: '-=300px'
        }, {
            queue: true,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).children('.comname').children('.comcontent').animate({
            right: '-=300px'
        }, {
            queue: true,
            duration: 500
        });

        $(this).children('.comname').children('.comtitle').animate({
            left: '+=300px'
        }, {
            queue: true,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).children('.comname').children('.comcontent').animate({
            right: '+=300px'
        }, {
            queue: true,
            duration: 500
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "overflow:hidden", but it will cut the "word" or the "letter" at the end of the container.

I would suggest you use the following JS library: http://jrvis.com/trunk8/

$('.truncate').trunk8({
  lines: 1
});
$('.truncate2').trunk8({
  lines: 2
});
$('.truncate3').trunk8({
  lines: 3
});

You would use the following classes everywhere in your project: "truncate", "truncate2" (for 2 lines), "truncate3" (for 3 lines).